# UITabBarController.selectedIndex does not change the tabBar icon?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

When using `UITabBarController` in my app, I cannot get the first item in it's `TabBar` to be selected (i.e. blue color). It just stays black and gray.

Is there another method to activate a certain item in the TabBar? I'm using:

```
self.tabController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

(For matter of interested, this is all instantiated in the AppDelegate as the delegate is handling a welcome view) which is, once dismissed removed from screen and the `UITabController.view` is taking over.

**Update**:

In the Main App Delegate, I use this code to show the tabController and set the index:

```
#pragma mark - Click handlers

- (void) startApp:(id)sender {
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.welcomeView
                        toView:self.tabController.view
                      duration:0 
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil];

    self.tabController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

`self.tabController` is not null, else I would not be able to see the view on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happening to me as well. I finally realized it came down to the way I was constructing the UITabBarItems for my tab views.  Being unable to find any examples of the proper way to provide the images for the tabs, I had settled on overridding tabBarItem in each of my views to return a UITabBarItem I had constructed myself. This appeared to load the icons properly but wouldn't change the higlight when I changed the selectedIndex programmatically.

Finally last night I found code like this in the init method of the child view controllers in an iOS book on Google Books:

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"];
self.tabBarItem.image = anImage;
```

Setting up the tab bar items this way fixed the problem with highlighting the correct button when switching tabs programmatically for me.

Comment: I'm creating a custom UITabBarItem in my controller and caching it in a property. Thus calls to - (UITabBarItem *)tabBarItem will maintain the selection state

Answer (score 1):

Is self.tabController nil?

```
  NSLog(@" my tab controller is 0x%x", self.tabController);
```

Comment: You either want `%@` (which prints [object description]) or `%p` (which prints a pointer). I usually use the former.

Comment: It's not nil as I can see the controllers view. Remember I'm in a AppDelegate, not in a `UIViewController` there (the delegate get's a signal from a view to dismiss the welcomeView and then start the real App.